# How to save HTML POST data temporary for later use?

Tags: php, mysql

I have registration form into 3 separate php pages as step 1, step 2 and step 3. i would like to know how to temporarily store the form data of page 1 & 2 until the user is reaching step 3  then retreive and send the data of all 3 forms together at once to the database, when the user clicks submit on page 3 after completing the 3rd form.

should i use cookies and/or sessions and database for temporary storage? and i saw someone is suggesting using hidden html inputs but i don't get it.

thanks.

Comment: The best way is to use session/cookies to store steps variables, but in each page you can also declares "<input type='hidden' name='variable' value='value' />", where variable is the name of values pass through steps. Thsi way you can maintain all step values. I hope it's understandble what i've said :)

Comment: Session variables "$_SESSION['variable']='value'" are available until you close the browser, so youn can access them on every page through "$_SESSION['variable']". Cookies variables works the same way, but you have to ask user to accept them because of "EU Legislation". So session variables are the best solution. After your form is submitted you can "erase" them like this "unsett($_SESSION['variable'])", or "session_destroy() - erase all session variables"

Comment: Does not PHP implement session handling by setting cookies?  So use of sessions will have the same requirement to obtain consent for cookies.

Comment: i'm not quite sure but there are some exceptions to the law

Comment: Perhaps this will help to clarify: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directive_on_Privacy_and_Electronic_Communications

Answer (score 1):

For the most time, hidden inputs will do.

Usage:
For example the user has posted "name=David" in Step 2.
Your server received that form data, and should insert this line into the Step 3 :

```
<input type="hidden" name="name" value="David">
```

When the user finished Step 3, your server will receive "name=David" again, so that you can handle all the data as a whole, without storing any data on the server.

Do this if the data from Step 1&2 are useless without Step 3.

Comment: Be careful to escape the data against XSS attacks when populating the hidden inputs.  Also beware that this design may perform badly with large amounts of form data and/or slow network connections (e.g. mobile devices).

Answer (score 0):

You can store your input data variables into session variables using PHP `$_session`

Comment: I would combine this with one of the above described methods.

Answer (score -1):

It would be best to save it in the sessions/cookies. Be sure to remove them once the submission takes place, otherwise everytime the user comes to the page, all will be filled with old data. What they meant by hidden input is that, on every step, your page is going to retrieve the data saved from previous page and then have them on the page hidden like `<input type="hidden" name="firstname" value="<?= $_POST['firstname']; ?>" />....`

Comment: By "session/cookies", I assume you mean store the data on the server in session memory and associate the client with that session via an identifier that is stored in a cookie?  In which case, I'm not sure I understand the caveat "*otherwise everytime...".  Or are you proposing storage of the data itself directly in cookies?  In which case, your caveat makes sense, but I'd be grateful if you could elaborate why you consider such a design to be "best"?

Comment: well you can use either one, session or cookies. Are you familiar with session or cookies? I would recommend using session in this case as session holds data for a short period of time by default.

Comment: Indeed, I am familiar with both; I was merely asking for your clarifications to your answer, as it appeared (to my mind) to be ambiguous.

Comment: Thanks, that explained what i exactly needed. Much appreciated! :)